# php for event calendar causing me to recieve html table/body/html end tag errors from my IDE in my code

Tags: php, calendar

all of the required closing tags are present, as well as function closing tags and php closing tags, I cant figure out the problem here. the errors state that Element 'table' requires end tag, Element 'body' requires end tag, and that Element 'html' requires end tag. here is the code in question:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // get the today date and store them in day month year variables
    $day = date('j');
    $month = date('n');
    $year = date('Y');

    //calendar variable
   $currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day");
   $monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp);
   $numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp);
   $counter = 0;




    ?>
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td id ="monthandyear" colspan="5"><?php echo $monthName." ".$year; ?></td>
            <td>asdf</td>


        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td class="days">Sun</td>
            <td class="days">Mon</td>
            <td class="days">Tue</td>
            <td class="days">Wed</td>
            <td class="days">Thu</td>
            <td class="days">Fri</td>
            <td class="days">Sat</td>

        </tr>

        <?php

            echo "<tr>";

                for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays + 1; $i++; $counter++){
                    $timeStamp = strtotime(""$year-$month-$i");
                    if ($i == 1){
                        $firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp);
                        for($j = 1; $j < $firstDay + 1; $counter++){
                            echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
                            }


                    }
                 if ($counter % 7 == 0){
                     echo "<tr></tr>"; }

                 echo "<td align = 'center'>".$i."</td>";

                }

            echo "</tr>";

        ?>
  </table> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra leading quote in your `strtotime()` call:

```
$timeStamp = strtotime(""$year-$month-$i");
```

should be

```
$timeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$i");
```

And so it looks like there's a PHP parse error causing the closing tags to not display.  Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Only the relevant code part, a bit cleaned up:

```
<?php
            echo "<tr>";

                for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays + 1; $i++)
                {
                    $timeStamp = strtotime($year-$month-$i);

                    if ($i == 1){
                       echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
                    }

                    if ($i % 7 == 0) {
                        echo "<tr></tr>";
                    }

                    echo "<td align='center'>".$i."</td>";

                }

            echo "</tr>";

        ?>
```

Comment: thanks for this, much simpler. What is the point of echoing a tr outside of the functions? im asking because i got this code from a tutorial and im trying to understand it all

Comment: The first tr starts the first row of days in the table. the last tr closes the last row of days in the table. everything in between is the day rendering loop. BUT the real problem with this is: i left out the day offset part. So the day numbers do not relate to the day...sry. But you got it already :)